# Rails 4 Asset Pipeline link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

While using the asset pipeline in production and trying to keep the folder less cluttered, I have set up nested folders. I am trying to link to a pdf within a sub-folder, but I am not sure how to call the file precisely.

```
<%= link_to ' | PDF', asset_path(pub.file), :target => "_blank" %>
```

This works in development. For production I will need to call `pubfiles/pub.file`, but that syntax seems like it is missing something.

I figured out it should be something like this:

```
<%= link_to ' | PDF', asset_path("pubfiles/#{pub.file}"), :target => "_blank" %>
```

But when I try to use the link I error out with:

Missing template people/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:pdf], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/rails/neuro/app/views"

```
def find(*args)
  find_all(*args).first || raise(MissingTemplate.new(self, *args))
end

def find_all(path, prefixes = [], *args)
```

In development without the folder argument setup, the pdf opens without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

When using `asset_path`, rails will prepend `/assets/` to the path you specified as its argument.

Thus make sure your sub-folder is within `assets` folder this way:

```
-public
  -assets
    -yourFolder
      -yourFile.ext
```

That way, you can use `asset_path` as `asset_path('yourFolder/yourFile.ext')` and rails will serve your file at `/assets/yourFolder/yourFile.ext`

Please notice that rails adds fingerprint to files in order to favor caching. Make sure your assets is properly compiled and configuration for production is properly defined.

Comment: Right, I have that nesting working properly. My question is `pub.file` is a database call where the file name is housed. I am trying to figure out how to append that call with the name of the folder within the asset folder.